# Key for Subclipse icons

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

Does anyone know of a comprehensive key for the range of Subclipse icons?

Comment: A comprehensive key has been posted as [an answer to another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248). It's much better than the one in linked in the existing answer to this question, because that one is missing a large number of icons.

Full disclosure: I asked that question. It was originally a dupe of this one because I didn't find it in search, so I focused the question to ask about a particular icon and someone went and made a full guide.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920248/657792) answer. There is more complete description

Comment: This answer is more complete:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They are all listed under Preferences > Team > SVN > Label decorations. Although they don't give an explanation of what they do.

This guy's blog post gives a good description of them: 
[Guide to subclipse icons](http://www.rorycullen.com/blog/2009/07/guide-to-subclipse-decorator-icons/)

I'm including a screenshot here in case the blog disappears: 
[image]

Comment: There's some new icons during the commit process (what is the A icon?) that aren't listed here.